# Using SAML2.0 for a OAuth2.0 token (Authorization code/Implicit grants)

Tags: oauth-2.0, dotnetopenauth, saml-2.0

Is it a good practice to use a SAML token in OAuth2 Authorization Code grant and Implicit grant? Or Should I use a different grant flow for that?

I've seen that Oauth2.0 Spec doesn't specify the token format, so I was wondering if I could adopt SAML2.0 format for this.

I am using DotNetOpenAuth Library to implement an Authorization Server.